# Hello there, i am getting this error while trying to upload WSDL in soupUi

Tags: java

i am getting this error while trying to upload WSDL in soupUi.!
It says 
Error loading [http://tradingcars.carwale.com/wsapis/tcapi.asmx?WSDL]:java.lang.Exception:
Failed to load url;http://tradingcars.carwale.com/wsapis/tcapi.asmx?WSDL,0-

Please gimme a solution if anyonw knows.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your url works with me.

http://tradingcars.carwale.com/wsapis/tcapi.asmx?WSDL

http://tradingcars.carwale.com/wsapis/tcapi.asmx?WSDL

Check your internet connection.

And do like this...
File --> New soapUI Project

[image]